# echo 3 column value (merge) php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to print my `address`, `state`, and `country` all in one `echo`.

This is how I call my column value:

```
echo $userRow['address'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate them:

```
echo $userRow['address'] . ', ' $userRow['state'] . ', ' . $userRow['country'];
```

You can use string substitution:

```
echo "{$userRow['address']}, {$userRow['state']}, {$userRow['country']}";
```

You can use `printf`:

```
printf ("%s, %s, %s", $userRow['address'], $userRow['state'], $userRow['country']);
```